# Using python ctypes to get buffer of floats from shared library into python string

Tags: python, pointers, return-value, ctypes

I'm trying to use python ctypes to use these two C functions from a shared library:

```
bool decompress_rgb(unsigned char *data, long dataLen, int scale)
float* getRgbBuffer()
```

The first function is working fine. I can tell by putting some debug code in the shared library and checking the input.

The problem is getting the data out. The RGB buffer is a pointer to a float (obviously) and this pointer stays constant during the life of the application. Therefore whenever I want to decompress an image, I call `decompress_rgb` and then need to see what's at the location pointed to by `getRgbBuffer`. I know that the buffer size is (720 * 288 * sizeof(float)) so I guess this has to come into play somewhere.

There's no `c_float_p` type so I thought I'd try this:

```
getRgbBuffer.restype = c_char_p
```

Then I do:

```
ptr = getRgbBuffer()
print "ptr is ", ptr
```

which just outputs:

```
ptr = 3078746120
```

I'm guessing that's the actual address rather than the content, but even if I was successfully dereferencing the pointer and getting the contents, it would only be the first char.

How can I get the contents of the entire buffer into a python string?

**Edit:** Had to change:

```
getRgbBuffer.restype = c_char_p
```

to

```
getRgbBuffer.restype = c_void_p
```

but then BastardSaint's answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not fully tested, but I think it's something along this line:

```
buffer_size = 720 * 288 * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)
rgb_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(buffer_size) 
ctypes.memmove(rgb_buffer, getRgbBuffer(), buffer_size)
```

Key is the `ctypes.memmove()` function. From the [ctypes documentation](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/reference.html):

> **`memmove(dst, src, count)`**
>   Same as the standard C memmove library function: copies `count` bytes from `src` to `dst`. `dst` and `src` must be integers or ctypes instances that can be converted to pointers.

After the above snippet is run, `rgb_buffer.value` will return the content up until the first `'\0'`. To get all bytes as a python string, you can slice the whole thing: `buffer_contents = rgb_buffer[:]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm definitely getting closer. At the moment the getRgbBuffer() pointer doesn't seem to match the one that is being returned by the C function. I'll keep battling on and come back to mark you correct when (or if!) I get it working.

Comment: If I change "getRgbBuffer.restype = c_char_p" to "getRgbBuffer.restype = c_void_p" then I get the correct address back from getRgbBuffer(). Unfortunately "print rgb_buffer.value" outputs nothing. :(

Comment: It's working now. Two things, first I needed the restype to be c_void_p and also to see the data I had to do "for a in rgb_buffer: print a". As I said, "print rgb_buffer.value" outputs nothing for some reason. If you could tweak your answer for those two points I'll mark it correct. Thanks again.

Comment: `print rgb_buffer.value` prints the contents up until the first null character:
    >>> import ctypes
    >>> b = ctypes.create_string_buffer(10)
    >>> b.value = 'a\0b'
    >>> b.value
    'a'
    >>> b[:]
    'a\x00b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Maybe that's why?

Anyway, glad it works now :)

Comment: Ah, my buffer may well have started with null values as it's RGB data. I've got pictures out of my C image decoder now. Very satisfying, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I used ctypes and I don't have something which returns a "double *" handy enough to test this out, but if you want a c_float_p:

```
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
```

Reading BastardSaint's answer, you just want the raw data, but I wasn't sure if you're doing that as a workaround to not having a c_float_p.